# Spliting Variable to count groups of double characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, count, null, hex

I want to be able to count the number of times "00" appears in a variable containing hex code.

This is to calculate the amount of NULL bytes contained within this code, so I have to count each 2 digits as 1.

```
48657920697420776f726b73000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Using the example hex code set to a variable, I have tried splitting it into a list such as

`['48' '65' '79' etc]`

and then counting but could not get it to work

Comment: *"could not get it to work"* - so where's the code, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you might have *very* long strings while counting the *NUL* bytes from a binary file, an iterator based approach might be preferred:

```
>>> s="48657920697420776f726b73000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>>> sum(1 if x == ('0','0') else 0 for x in zip(*[iter(s)]*2))
18
```

Comment: Thank you. Both answers work well and give the same results, but have used this one

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
line = '48657920697420776f726b73000000000000000000000000000000000000'
n = 2
list = [line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]
list.count('00')
```

You can see a working sample [here](http://repl.it/Xil)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks works great, I had something very close to this, just not quite there

Comment: I'm also start to learning python so sometimes I'm stuck with things like this. I'm glad to help you :).